# preserveNullAndEmptyArrays not working in pyspark - It should be a list of pipeline stages (Documents) or a single pipeline stage (Document)

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark, mongodb-atlas

```
I have a pipeline like this. However, when I try to read this with pyspark i get the following error:


pipeline = [
    {
        '$addFields': {
            'paymentTerms': {
                '$objectToArray': '$paymentTerms'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'managers': {
                '$objectToArray': '$managers'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'details': {
                '$objectToArray': '$details'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'invitation': {
                '$objectToArray': '$invitation'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'paymentTerms': '$paymentTerms.v'
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'managers': '$managers.v'
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'details': '$details.v'
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'invitation': '$invitation.v'
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'updatedAt': {
                '$dateToString': {
                    'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S', 
                    'date': '$updatedAt'
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$documents', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$paymentTerms', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$managers', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$details', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$invitation', 
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    }
]
```

```
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid Aggregation map Map(uri -> mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@vdev.mongodb.net/, database -> v-dev, pipeline -> [{'$addFields': {'paymentTerms': {'$objectToArray': '$paymentTerms'}}}, {'$addFields': {'managers': {'$objectToArray': '$managers'}}}, {'$addFields': {'details': {'$objectToArray': '$details'}}}, {'$addFields': {'invitation': {'$objectToArray': '$invitation'}}}, {'$addFields': {'paymentTerms': '$paymentTerms.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'managers': '$managers.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'details': '$details.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'invitation': '$invitation.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'updatedAt': {'$dateToString': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S', 'date': '$updatedAt'}}}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$documents', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$paymentTerms', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$managers', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$details', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$invitation', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}], collection -> travel-rfps):%njava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid pipeline option: [{'$addFields': {'paymentTerms': {'$objectToArray': '$paymentTerms'}}}, {'$addFields': {'managers': {'$objectToArray': '$managers'}}}, {'$addFields': {'details': {'$objectToArray': '$details'}}}, {'$addFields': {'invitation': {'$objectToArray': '$invitation'}}}, {'$addFields': {'paymentTerms': '$paymentTerms.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'managers': '$managers.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'details': '$details.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'invitation': '$invitation.v'}}, {'$addFields': {'updatedAt': {'$dateToString': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S', 'date': '$updatedAt'}}}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$documents', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$paymentTerms', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$managers', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$details', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}, {'$unwind': {'path': '$invitation', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True}}].
 It should be a list of pipeline stages (Documents) or a single pipeline stage (Document)
```

i use the pyspark connector

```
dyf = spark.read\\

.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")\\

.option("uri", "mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@vdev.net/")\\

.option("database", "v-dev")\\

.option("pipeline",pipeline)\\

.option("collection", "travel-questionnaires")\\

.load()
```

When I remove the preserveNullAndEmptyArrays parameter, I am able to successfully excecute the query however, the data is missing rows.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !